# How to change the legend title of my ggplots based on outcomes?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wonder if there is an efficent way to change the legend title of my ggplots based on outcomes.

Example

I have a function which helps me to filter a data base by type and by county.

df without filter

```
county   | date        |  value   | type
-----------------------------------
Alameda    2020-01-01      6         positive
Alameda    2020-01-02      2         negative
Alameda    2020-01-03      1         positive
LA         2020-01-04      4         positive
LA         2020-01-03      1         positive
```

** Function **

```
function_forggplot <- function(data =  df,
                          select_county = "Alameda",
                          type_order = unique(df$type)) {


#Filter data base
df_outcome <- df[df$county %in% select_county,]
df_outcome <- df_outcome[df_outcome$type %in% type_order,]

gg_outcome <- ggplot(
    data = df_outcome,
    aes(x = date,
        y = value,
        color = type
    )) +
    geom_line(size = .5)
```

I want change the legend title of my ggplot2 based on the outcome for example if the user select county= LA and type =  positive. I want a title in my ggplot like "Results positives for LA".
With if else conditionals works but I have more than 100 cases so I think this not a good option.

**Expect outcome**

function_forggplot(county="Alameda", type = "negatives")
A ggplot object with this title "Results negatives for Alameda"

function_forggplot(county="Fresno", type = "postives")
A ggplot object with this title "Results pisitives for Fresno"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We can create the function with `glue` as it is very flexible to get objects specified within `{}`.  Of course, we can use `paste` or `sprintf` as well.  Anyway, `ggplot` is an external package.  So using, another package from the `tidyverse`, would make this more tidier.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
f1 <- function(dat, county_nm, type_nm) {
          dat %>%
            filter(county == county_nm, type == type_nm) %>%
            ggplot(aes(x = date, y = value)) + 
              geom_line() + 
              ggtitle(glue::glue("Results {type_nm} for {county_nm}"))
      }
```

then, we call as

```
f1(df, 'LA', 'positive')
```

-output

[image]

---

Or without any packages (other than `ggplot2`, `dplyr`)

```
f2 <- function(dat, county_nm, type_nm) {
          dat %>%
            filter(county == county_nm, type == type_nm) %>%
            ggplot(aes(x = date, y = value)) + 
              geom_line() + 
              ggtitle(sprintf("Results %s for %s", type_nm, county_nm))
      }
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(county = c("Alameda", "Alameda", "Alameda", "LA", 
"LA"), date = structure(c(18262, 18263, 18264, 18265, 18264), class = "Date"), 
    value = c(6L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L), type = c("positive", "negative", 
    "positive", "positive", "positive")), row.names = c(NA, -5L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt the code you showed in the function directly like this. Also you can use `paste0()` for the title (no need of other packages):

```
library(ggplot2)
#Function
funplot <- function(df, select_county, type_order) {
  #Filter data base
  df_outcome <- df[df$county == select_county,]
  df_outcome <- df_outcome[df_outcome$type == type_order,]
  #Plot
  ggplot(df_outcome,aes(x = date, y = value)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    ggtitle(paste0("Results ",select_county," for ",type_order))
}
#Apply
funplot(mydf, 'Alameda', 'positive')
```

Output:

[image]

Some data used:

```
#Data
mydf <- structure(list(county = c("Alameda", "Alameda", "Alameda", "LA", 
"LA"), date = structure(c(18262, 18263, 18264, 18265, 18264), class = "Date"), 
    value = c(6L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L), type = c("positive", "negative", 
    "positive", "positive", "positive")), row.names = c(NA, -5L
), class = "data.frame")
```